# Prevent label text overlapping background image set on label (jquery validate)

Tags: css, jquery-validate

I've set a background image to the jquery genrated validate label.

```
my-form#formy label.error
{
background: url("/bad.gif") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:400px;
height:10px;
font-size:6px;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

The problem is that when the text is too long and wraps over 2 lines, it sometimes obscures the image.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks in anticipation,

Answer (score 0):

Set `white-space:nowrap` style to your labels to prevent wrapping to the second line.